# What's the standard way to generate a url like stuff?

Tags: php, url

```
$arr = array('key1'=>'val1','key2'=>'val2');
$str = '';
foreach($arr as $k=>$v)
{
    $str .= '&' . $k . '=' . urlencode($v);
}
echo substr($str,1);
```

Or

```
$arr = array('key1'=>'val1','key2'=>'val2');
$str = '';
foreach($arr as $k=>$v)
{
    $str .= '&' . urlencode($k) . '=' . urlencode($v);
}
echo substr($str,1);
```

Does the `$k` need to be urlencoded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes;
If you use PHP5 i Guess the http_build_query would be just what you need ;)

http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php